# Postgres look for rows with same value and compare the timestamp, then update the old rows

Tags: postgresql

I have a question. Given the  rows as below in a table, how can I write a query to look for the 2 rows and then compare the last_updated timestamp column? After that, I need to update the older timestamp's flag and timestamp effective_to's date. I am working in a postgres database and i need a query on how i can do this update.

Hope I can seek help from you all.

Before:

```
ID    Effective_from           Effective_to   Latest_flag                     
1      2017-12-11               9999-12-31        Y
1      2017-12-12               9999-12-31        Y
```

After: (update the older timestamp values after comparing both rows)

```
ID    Effective_from           Effective_to   Latest_flag                     
1      2017-12-11               2017-12-12        N
1      2017-12-12               9999-12-31        Y
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: This data shows us the "before." What is the "after?" *"I need to update the older timestamp's flag and timestamp effective_to's date."* Update them to what?

Comment: @cdhowie,  I need to update the timestamp's for "effective_to" to the latest "effective_from" from the latest rows and then update the latest flag to "Y".

Comment: @cdhowie I have updated my questions, hope the clearer questions can show what i wanted.

Comment: BTW: there are -infinity/+infinity pseudo-values for dates and timestamps. So, you don't have to use `9999-12-31` as *extremely beyond* value.

Comment: @wildplasser thanks for the advice! will use that on my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not be fast, but it will work in one query.  This uses window functions to peek at the next row within an ordered group of rows (here defined by the window `idgroup`).  Replace `table_a` with the actual name of your table.

Read `lead(x, y, z)` as "the value of `x` from the row `y` rows after this row in the window, unless there is no such row, in which case the value of `z` from *this* row."  So `lead(false, 1, true)` is a sneaky way to say "`true` if this is the last row in the window, otherwise false."

```
WITH update_data AS (
    SELECT
        uniqueid,
        effective_from,
        lead(effective_from, 1, effective_to) OVER idgroup AS new_effective_to,
        lead(false, 1, true) OVER idgroup AS new_latest
    FROM table_a
    WINDOW idgroup AS (PARTITION BY uniqueid ORDER BY effective_from ASC)
)
UPDATE table_a
SET effective_to = update_data.new_effective_to,
    latest_flag = update_data.new_latest
FROM update_data
WHERE table_a.uniqueid = update_data.uniqueid AND table_a.effective_from = update_data.effective_from;
```

You could create a view that will project the values of `effective_to` and `latest_flag` without having to realize and maintain them in an actual table.  If we remove the `effective_to` and `latest_flag` from the table and create this view:

```
CREATE VIEW table_a_extended AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        lead(effective_from, 1, null) OVER idgroup AS effective_to,
        lead(false, 1, true) OVER idgroup AS latest_flag
    FROM table_a
    WINDOW idgroup AS (PARTITION BY uniqueid ORDER BY effective_from ASC)
);
```

The results are:

```
 uniqueid |     created_at      |        last_update         |    name    |       effective_from       |        effective_to        | latest_flag
----------+---------------------+----------------------------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-------------
 65617035 | 2017-12-10 00:00:00 | 2017-12-10 09:23:10.735    | TESTING    | 2017-12-10 09:23:10.735    | 2017-12-11 09:23:10.735929 | f
 65617035 | 2017-12-11 00:00:00 | 2017-12-11 09:23:10.735929 | Stargazing | 2017-12-11 09:23:10.735929 |                            | t
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help! I have managed to get the results as you said!  Also i need to update this into my actual table as we need to keep track of the changes made.

Comment: Just to add 1 more help from you, how can i set the  
latest flag = false rows's effective_to timestamp to be deduct 1 minute from the latest flag = true row's effective_from timestamp?